# mkfs fs-options for ext2 loopback device for backup

Tags: filesystems, loopback, ext2

I'm looking to create a loopback device for local temporary backup storage. This will be used to store ~1000 files in ~20 directories.

I understand I'd need to use the `mkfs` command along the lines of:

```
mkfs -t ext2 [ fs-options ] /path/to/image
```

What I don't understand is:

- What fs-options options are available for an ext2 filesystem?
- Whether the defaults, whatever they may be, would be acceptable?
- What fs-options might be suitable for my needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just go with the defaults (i.e. no options); they work quite well in most cases.

If you're planning to store many small files or few big files, you *could* benefit from changing the block size... but it's usually not worth the hassle.